# Cambiar texto de una etiqueta p con clases repetidas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

si tengo por ejemplo:

```
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion()">Texto1</p>
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion()">Texto2</p>
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion()">Texto3</p>
```

¿como hago para que a través de jQuery me cambie solo el texto de la etiqueta p clickada? No puedo usar ids, ni varias clases.
Con

```
$('.miclase').text(nuevo texto')
```

Obvamiente me cambia el texto en todos los p de la misma clase.

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque el ejemplo es en JS, puedes fácilmente pasarlo a JQuery.

- Tomamos todos los elementos que comparten a la misma clase y los almacenamos en una variable
- Iteramos los elementos que esa variable contiene en un ciclo `forEach`
- Al parámetro que nos representa a cada elemento en las iteraciones que hace el ciclo le damos un listener en su evento click
- Posterior modificamos a este parámetro el valor que tiene en su propiedad `innerText` dándole un contenido personalizado

```html
      <p class="miclase">Texto1</p>
      <p class="miclase">Texto2</p>
      <p class="miclase">Texto3</p> 
    
    <script>
      let textos = document.querySelectorAll('.miclase');
      
      textos.forEach((texto) => {
        texto.addEventListener('click', () => {
          texto.innerText = `Contenido: ${Math.random().toFixed(1)}`;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

De esta manera empleas a la misma clase que se comparten los 3 párrafos, sacas a la lógica del llamado de la función del HTML y evitas que el mismo texto se aplique a todos los elementos.

**Referencias**

- [ciclo each JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [Selector de múltiples elementos en JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)
- [Método html en JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Muy buen explicación. +1

Comment: Podrías usar delegación de eventos así te ahorras iterar y crear `n` EventListener

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasar como argumento, en la llamada a la función, la instancia del elemento `p` sobre el que se ha realizado el clic del usuario, usando `this`.

Para el efecto, he agregado un argumento llamado `sender` con el que haré referencia al elemento, dentro de la función:

```js
function accion(sender) {
  sender.innerHTML = 'nuevo texto';
}
```

```html
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion(this)">Texto1</p>
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion(this)">Texto2</p>
<p class="miclase" onclick="accion(this)">Texto3</p>
```